# Exception Handling for specifc exception type

Tags: c#, exception

I need to catch a generic exception and then categorize is based on a specific type to reduce the no of lines of code as all the exception does the same thing .

Something like below

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Type ExceptionType = ex.GetType();
           switch (ExceptionType.ToString())
            {
                 
                case "IOException":
                case "NullReferenceException":
                system.WriteLine((ExceptionType)ex.Message);
                break;
    }
```

This shows error there is no type Exception type. Is there a possiblity to try this approach and accomplish this or need to take a typical if else approach.
Please help

Comment: What is the end goal here? If all exception are handled the same way, why do you need to do any categorization?

Comment: `ToString()` will also include the namespace, so it wouldn't match any of those. You'd need `System.IO.IOException` etc., but you're better to filter with the types themselves, than mangle them into strings first.

Comment: @JonasH The end goal is that based on the exception type say ioexception ,
the message varies accordingly . Hence this approach is required to make it generic

Comment: @MartinCostello Could you provide an example ?

Comment: Use pattern matching `switch(ex){ case IOException: case NullReferenceException: ...` or create a logging function and call it from separate catch blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should handling each Exception individually like so:

```
try
{
    
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // Log specific IO Exception
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    // Log Specific Null Reference Exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Catch everything else
}
```

You could do:

```
    string exceptionErrorMessage;
    
    try
    {
    
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // Log specific IO Exception
        exceptionErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        // Log Specific NullReferenceException
        exceptionErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Catch everything else
        exceptionErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exceptionErrorMessage))
    {
        // use your logger to log exception.
        Console.WriteLine(exceptionErrorMessage);
    }
```

Here's the correct to OPs code using the same method he wanted:

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var exType = e.GetType().Name;
    switch (exType)
    {
        case "IOException":
        case "NullReferenceException":
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to create a logging function which you call from those specific cases

Comment: @Charlieface, yeah i'd use my logger within each catch for simple answer i just consoled it like he originally did.

Comment: @LeeStevens The main idea here is to eliminate the use of multiple different catch block instead use a single catch block and categories type of some specific exception type and print it. The single line of print is used in different catch blocks. I wanted to try if there is a way to not use different catchblock

Comment: @DheenaDayalan, i have updated my answer to fix your example (at the bottom). That should work fine (haven't tested).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may be looking for ex.GetType().Name!

In terms of a full solution, that should work with your existing code.